# Connect Parse-Dashboard with Parse-Server (Docker-Container)

Tags: node.js, docker, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-dashboard

maybe someone can help me with my problem.

My Plan is to set up a parse-server (https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server)  and connect the parse-dashboard (https://github.com/parse-community/parse-dashboard/) to them.
I want to use docker container for the instances. So I have 3 containers (MongoDB, parse-server, parse-dashboard).

Actually the parse-server and the database are running an I could safe and query one test-object.
But my problem is, that the dashboard doesn´t connect to the server. When I call the dashboard with the browser, I get the login screen and can login with my credetials but next I get a white website.

I read the docs and guides a few times and tried different configurations, but unfortunally I can´t find my problem.

Here is my `docker-compose.yaml`: (I have tested without the SSL-Configuration too.)

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  parse-server:
    image: parseplatform/parse-server
    environment:
      - PARSE_SERVER_APPLICATION_ID=myAPP
      - PARSE_SERVER_MASTER_KEY=myKEY
      - PARSE_SERVER_DATABASE_URI=mongodb://mongo/test
    ports:
      - "1337:1337"
    links:
      - mongodb-server:mongo
    depends_on:
     - "mongodb-server"
  mongodb-server:
    image: mongo
  parse-dashboard:
    image: parseplatform/parse-dashboard
    ports:
      - "4040:4040"
    volumes:
      - ./parse-dashboard/config.json:/src/Parse-Dashboard/parse-dashboard-config.json
      - ./parse-dashboard/ca.key:/src/Parse-Dashboard/ca.key
      - ./parse-dashboard/ca.crt:/src/Parse-Dashboard/ca.crt
    environment:
      - PARSE_DASHBOARD_SSL_KEY=/src/Parse-Dashboard/ca.key
      - PARSE_DASHBOARD_SSL_CERT=/src/Parse-Dashboard/ca.crt
    links:
      - parse-server:parse-server
    depends_on:
      - parse-server
```

And here is the `config.json` for the Dashboard:

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
          "serverURL":"http://parse-server:1337/parse",
          "appId":"myAPP",
          "masterKey":"myKEY"
    }
  ],
  "users": [
    {
          "user":"myNAME",
          "pass":"myPW"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: can you be more specific about 
>  but next I get a white website.
What's the HTTP status code? Is there an error in the browser's console? Screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested your configs, but it seems that the problem isn't the parseserver itself, but your config file!

I think you should probably use `http://localhost:1337/parse` instead of `http://parse-server:1337/parse`.

The reason, as far as I can tell, is that your config file will be read by parse server and not by docker, so the host `parse-server` won't exist for parse itself.